Can not access of my own folders in Ubuntu distro + GNOME
when I switched off my computer, I opened it and saw it different and I found myself not the owner of the computer + I can't access on my own folders even by the PC password. I tried mount some file and remount it with access read and write, but nothing changes, restart my computer, ask AI. Nothing benefit...
The question is

What is the reason of this problem?
And How can I return my PC like when I install Ubuntu?

I tried to change the owner from root to my 'hamza', It shows me an error 'couldn't modify read-only files'. I went to modify read-only files and it take much time then shows me the mission completed, but I saw nothing changes
sudo unmount /mnt/Peace

then remount it by the features of read and write
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda3 mnt/Peace

then I tried
sudo chown -R hamza:users mnt/Peace

and also
sudo chmod 755 ../../mnt/Peace
sudo chmod 777 ../../mnt/Peace


Are you really using the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release you tagged?  That release reached EOSS many years ago, and as such is off-topic now.  If a RW partition/file-systems flips to RO, I'd suggest reading your system logs as to WHY this occurred, as the reason should be worked out BEFORE trying to resolve an issue; otherwise you risk data loss due to ignored problem.

Use smartctl -a on the disk device to check if it has failed.

@guiverc Yes, I'm using LTS release. What is RW and RO ?! I accidentally tried to install Notion app "for productivity", I found the the screen turned on black and my desktop disappears. So, I had to install GNOME again, and I found this happened

If a file-system is READ-WRITE (RW) allowing changes to data, and certain error(s) are detected on it that will cause dataloss; the fs mount will flip to RO (READ-ONLY) to prevent dataloss, allowing the owner/operator to check logs for clues as to problem & thus act on them.. such as failing disk etc.. This preserves whatever life remains for data recovery; as each change moving forward can do more damage if you have a failing disk...  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is End of Standard Support and supported only by Canonical; it's five years of standard supported ended in 2019-April.

@guiverc I'm realy sorry for this mistake, I meant 24..04.1 LTS. Not the old version. How could I found what is the mistake in my distro to solve it because I'm start learning Linux from Free Code Camp and I'm not understanding what happens yet. So, how could you help me in that? Thanks a lot for your time.
